# what is intel x86 atom system image in android sdk manager?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I am setting up development environment. 
So my question is, what is Intel x86 atom system image in Android SDK manager? 
Should i install it or not?
The option is present in API level 15 & 16 but not in 17.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to install this on your host machine: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> So my question is, what is intel x86 atom system image in android sdk manager?

It is a version of the Android emulator that runs natively on x86 CPUs, like those in most development machines.

Contrast that with the ARM system image, which contains ARM (not x86) CPU instructions, and therefore must be translated when run.

> Should i install it or not?

The x86 emulator images, where available, tend to run faster. You will have to do some work on your development machine to take advantage of them, as is outlined [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm).

> the option is present in api level 15 & 16 but not in 17.

AFAIK Google relies upon Intel to create these images, and Intel has only done so on a few API levels.

Comment: Shamelessly asking on question for you, intel-atom-x86-image will work on AMD processors with same performance in Ubuntu ? !

Comment: @LOG_TAG: You would have to see if Ubuntu KVM supports your AMD processor.

Comment: if KVM is supported in AMD processor it will give equal performance as Intel ? really confused I need to buy a new Intel System or not for Android !

Comment: @LOG_TAG: Sorry, but I have not tried the emulator with an AMD CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I changed my system to Intel i5 proc only for supporting Intel atom x86, performance is really bad in AMD compare to Intel!

Comment: When I get a new update for the System Image, do I need to create a new emulator from scratch to take advantage of the new features? Please elaborate.

Comment: @powder366: I think so. Creating an AVD used to create a copy of the images. I have not looked into this recently, so it is possible that they changed the system.

Answer (score 11):

The x86 Android* emulator system image enables you to run an emulation of Android on your development machine. In combination with the Android SDK, you can test your Android applications on a virtual Android device based on Intel Architecture

> Whether I should install this?

Yes, if you are using Intel processor. To check if your intel processor support Virtualization Technology(VT), use [**Intel Processor Identification Utility**](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=7838) tool.

> Note: If your CPU does not support virtualization technology(VT),
>   then you cannot use virtual machine acceleration.

In order to install the emulator image add-on, you can use the Android SDK Manager (Recommended Method):

[**Install Guide(Recommended Method)**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-kitkat-4-4-installation-instructions-recommended)

Alternately, you can download the binary zip file and unzip and copy the included directory into the add-ons directory of your Android SDK installation. (Note that this method does not allow for automatic updates of the add-on):

[**Install Guide(Alternate/Manual Method)**](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to place `ntel x86 atom system image` inside Android SDK. Where should I place it? I have downloaded folder of `ntel x86 atom system image`

Comment: @user6750923 Refer this documentation on [Intel® Atom™ x86 Image for Android* 4.4 KitKat Installation Instructions - Manually](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually)

Comment: All virtual devices are placed inside x86 folder? (Suggested in your link)

Comment: @user6750923 I'm not sure what you're asking but here's your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024685/installing-intel-x86-atom-system-images-offline-manually-for-android If you still face problem please do a search for similar questions or ask a new one instead.

Comment: I successfully placed x86 folder of Virtual Device (Downloaded) inside `system-images\android-23\google_apis` and successfully able to run the Virtual device. I am finding about more than one Virtual devices. I think; x86 image of other devices (downloaded) should be placed inside `system-images\<API LEVEL>\google_apis` Thanks for your help.