# Installing Intel x86 Atom System Images offline (manually) for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I want to install the Intel x86 Atom System Image because my emulator speed is too slow. Each time  I tried to install it from the Android sdk manager I failed getting this message:-

Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml

Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml

```
Done loading packages.

Preparing to install archives

Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1

  Resuming Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1 download at 1540 (0%)

Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected ddb3313e8dcd07926003f7b828eafea1115ea35b, got 2789383f5a408e854f56ae282de281260fa2b46d.
Done. 

Nothing was installed.
```

I went to the Intel site and downloaded it manually and then followed the instructions to install it. But when I create  a new AVD I don't see the Intel atom option in the CPU/ABI menu.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: _"Each time I tried to install it from the Android sdk manager I failed"_ How does it fail? What error did you get? Post this, thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have Android SDK and ADT v22.6.2 installed as these versions fixed a lot of installation-related issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I have installed it from Android SDK Manager successfully .

I found the problem , I should close the eclipse while downloading and installing the software  , because eclipse.exe  locks adt-bundle-windows-x86 folder.

But eclipse must show  a message that saying :- you must close eclipse.exe !

Answer (score 12):

If you are unable to install Intel x86 System images using Android SDK, then you can always download them directly from the Intel website and install it manually,

Intel has provided easy-to-follow instructions to download and install Intel System images for Android manually,

here is one tutorial on installing [Intel® Atom™ x86 Image for Android* 4.4 KitKat Manually](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually)

The above instructions would help you to install System Image for Android 4.4 kitkat, but
Intel has also provided direct links for all other Android versions on its own website,

for your convenience, here are the direct links for x86 System Images from Intel website,

### Android x86 System Images

- [Android 4.4 (KitKat) ›](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-4-4-kitkat-x86-emulator-system-image)
- [Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) ›](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-43-jelly-bean-x86-emulator-system-image)
- [Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) ›](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-4-2-jelly-bean-x86-emulator-system-image)
- [Android 4.1.1 (Jelly Bean) ›](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-41-jelly-bean-x86-emulator-system-image)
- [Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) ›](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-ice-cream-sandwich-x86-emulator-image/)
- [Android 2.3.7 (Gingerbread) ›](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-237-gingerbread-x86-emulator-image-add-on/)

furthermore, You may visit [Intel Android Tools](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/tools) page if new images are added in future.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue , and error message was like this,

> Downloading Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 14 Download interrupted: Read timed out Done. Nothing was
>   installed.

After, i downloaded the image file , in my case https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sysimg_x86-23_r14.zip

Then i extracted it , and copied the folder x86 to following path, in my case it is

C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-23\x86\

Then it showed in the installed packages list.

Comment: PHP? Did that help for an android image-problem? How come?

Comment: @SilverSkin Thanks for pointing out the url path, it was accidental , i corrected it.