# Is it safe to remove system.img from android sdk?

Tags: android

I realized that there are like 10 of them in my sdk . They make my sdk very large because each of these images are about 1 gb.  Would I damage my development environment if i delete some of them? I use android studio btw

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072832/what-is-intel-x86-atom-system-image-in-android-sdk-manager

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These images contain different variants of Android emulators. You can delete some of them to make your SDK smaller. But I strongly suggest you to do it from SDK manager. There you can find all of them and delete that you don't really need:
[image]

Also there you can manage what else you need in SDK and what you don't. Maybe you don't need old versions of SDK, maybe some documentation. If the place is critical for you just go to SDK manager and remove all that you don't really whant to have in SDK. 
I think it is better than remove something manually. At least it is reliable way to change SDK installation

Answer (score 3):

These images in the sdk are used to test different android versions on the emulator. If you have no need to test for a certain OS version you can safely delete its corresponding image file (along with the other images in that directory)